# How do I merge multiple animated Armatures?

Tags: animation, armature, baking

I have multiple armatures, each doing its own thing something like this:

[image]

I want to merge all the armatures and bake all actions into one.

The problem is if I try to select all armatures and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, only one of the armatures keeps its action, the rest looses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

- Copy all armatures in object mode and merge by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. You will lose animation data, but this not a problem, we will copy keyframes from separate ones.
- Enter the Pose Mode and add one keyframe to all bones. We need this to get animation tracks.
- Now move to the dope sheet editor and copy all keyframes from the separate armatures. When select new one and paste keyframes there.
- Now you don't need old armatures, remove them

Comment: that's what I needed, Thank you very much!!